# Hardware Enablement Stake update make mouuse invisble on Freya

Tags: release-freya, updates, greeter, hardware, mouse

I have reverted back to Freya with a fresh install due to kernel/display incompatibility with Loki on my machine. Now, on Freya, when I updated in response to a warning regarding Hardware Enablement Stake. But after that, my mouse is invisible when I resume from suspend moreover, sometimes login screen don't show/unresponsive. I will be thankful if someone suggests a solution and which package creating this mess.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to upgrade to Loki. Loki contains a newer hardware support stack including a new Intel driver that doesn't have the mouse cursor issue.

Comment: Thank you, actually, I downgraded to Freya due to unable to resume from suspend....which is what happening with this update too.